# Product recommendation duplicated when using Adobe Sensei

Tags: magento2, product, adobe-sensei

I'm using a Magento 2 Commerce Cloud + Adobe Sensei product recommendation

I did all the steps described in the [DevDocs - Product Recommendations](https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/product-recs.html) but when I enabled the AI product recommendations, it didn't stop my native product recommendations, so there are 2 recommendation blocks in my product page.

How could I void this?

Comment: I am facing strange issue. In product recommendations it returns null for product  url, you have any idea about it?

Comment: HI @Rafael Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/340422/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just disable the current product recommendations via the admin panel, **Marketing > Related Products Rules** as the image below.

[image: Disabling product recommendation in Magento 2 Commerce Cloud]

Or you can do it via code removing the recommended products block via XML in your theme.