# Magento 2.4.2 : Adobe Sensei Product Recommendations need to Display on Custom Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, adobe-sensei, product-recommendation

I am using **Magento 2.4.2 Enterprise Version**. I have created one custom router in my instance & set as home page.

After I created Adobe Sensei Product Recommendations rule from admin. All types of rule created like "**Trending**", "**Recommendations for you**" etc. But, It's not displaying on home page.

I also created custom router XML file and call product recommendations template file on home page. But, still it's not display.

How to display it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be showing because Adobe Sensei needs behavioural data to show recommendations. Make sure the sandbox ID is configured, make some orders and access some products logged in, then run the CRON to push the data to the Adobe Sensei server.

**Custom pages**

You can use it normally in custom pages, although, I recommend using the page builder integration to make it easier.

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder-product-recommendations
```

I recommend checking these two links about the test scenarios too:

[Why Adobe sensei recommended products don't show products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318223/16416)

[Magento AI Recommendations Tests](https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/test.html)

[Mastering Magento 2 + AI Product Recommendation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mastering-magento-2-ai-product-recommendation-rafael-corr%C3%AAa-gomes)

Comment: Thanks for answer !! But, default page type for ex : category page, product page, cart page etc it's working fine. Only on custom page it's not showing. I need to implement it using adobe sensei. Can you please guide me?

Comment: what in a staging environment if we want to show recently viewed items on homepage. Do we need to configure any corn or indexers for it ?